# How to properly shim jquery / Backbone using browerify-shim

Tags: javascript, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to build a standalone JS lib that uses backbone/jquery. Here's a [sample repo](https://github.com/bradrobertson/browserify_shim_example) that represents the lib I'm trying to build.

I have a few goals for this lib:

1. Don't expose ANY globals (ie wrap everything properly so nothing leaks)
2. Don't be affected by any other package tools like requireJS

   - This lib could be loaded into any other website and I don't want any conflicts with JS that *might* be there (which is beyond my control) such as requireJS

So, my understanding is that I can use browserify-shim to properly shim these modules such that they can be used as expected with `require` in browserify. I'm pretty sure the shim is supposed to undef `defines` and `require` when it wraps these modules, which would achieve goal #2. Goal #1 would hopefully then be achieved just by using browserify as expected.

I can't really seem to get this to work and I"m not sure if it's just my misunderstanding of  browserify-shim. I seem to have the same problem whether or not I run browserify from the command line: `browserify src/main.js -o build/main.js` or using the gulp build.

Basically, it's as if `browserify-shim` isn't even running. If you open up the index.html, you can see that the requirejs code I've loaded in is *definitely* affecting my lib as `Backbone` is just an empty object, then requirejs crashes.

You can see my package.json [here](https://github.com/bradrobertson/browserify_shim_example/blob/master/package.json) in the repo, and it looks roughly like this:

```
{
...
"browserify-shim": {
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js": "$",
    "./node_modules/underscore.js": "_",
    "./node_modules/backbone.js": {
      "exports": "Backbone",
      "depends": [
        "./node_modules/underscore.js",
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^4.1.11",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.6.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "jquery": "^1.11.0",
    "underscore": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, but I'm having no luck. I was wondering if anyone can help or at least corroborate that what I'm trying to achieve is correct and possible with `browserify-shim`.

Thanks.

### edit

To illustrate that it's definitely not shimming the modules, I've created a `build/main.js` and a `build/main-shimmed.js` that are exactly the same. The main.js I ran with no shim config and the shimmed one had the above config. I'm clearly missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Browserify and Browserify-shim are working in this case, and your main.js is calling the right require.

The problem you are running into is the that libraries you are bundling are also attempting to wire up the AMD style configuration.  Your "crossing the streams", beware of Gozer.

Either get versions without the AMD configuration loaders, or comment them out.

Comment: I've just added to the question. I tried a build with and without shimming and they're identical. So it's definitely not working the way I want. Also, but understanding of browserify-shim is that it actually undefs any global AMD methods (ie `define`) so it *should* be fine to use the source file I'm using. I dont' really get the motivation otherwise if I can use the official src from npm.